# Solve synthesis equation for Dirac delta function in a direct way

Tags: integration, improper-integrals, fourier-transform, complex-integration, dirac-delta

I know that $ \delta (x) =  \frac{1}{2 \pi } \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} e^{iwx}dw$ and I know indirect methods to solve this.

But I can't solve the integral in a **direct way**. I tried [this site](https://www.integral-calculator.com) to show me the steps, but it couldn't solve it either.

Can somebody help me to solve this integral in a direct way?
$$ 
 \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} e^{iwx}dw
$$
thanks in advance.

P.S: my mean of a direct way: to solve it by solving the integral not saying that: "it is the synthesis equation for the Dirac delta so it is Dirac delta by using the Fourier transform"

Comment: What do you mean by "direct way"? And in which sense do you want to compute that integral (e.g.: in the sense of distribution, in the sense of hyperfunction)?

Comment: I mean to solve it by solving the integral not saying that: "it is the synthesis equation for the Dirac delta so it is  Dirac delta".

Comment: sorry, I'm just a student and I know nothing about " sense of distribution, in the sense of hyperfunction", sorry :(

Comment: The problem is that this integral is neither defined in the sense of Riemann improper integration neither in the sense of Lebesgue integration, so you have to deal with more advanced theories to give a meaning to that integral... probably the indirect methods you were talking about are just how you calculate integrals in these more generalized context...

Comment: You cannot solve this integral in the usual sense, because it is not well-defined. You need distribution theory to understand this properly. The integral notation is used here because it just reminds us of the usual Fourier transform, and $\widehat{\delta} = 1$.

Comment: OMG! so that is the point! thank you @Bob and @ Sobi :) I was really confused about this integral! thanks :)